# Pasting numbers as a value: error message "value stored as text"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy some numbers and paste it in another sheet as a value.
I was hoping the following code would do the trick but it doesn't...

```
Sheets("test2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
```

But instead of pasting the numbers as a value, it gives me an error message saying that the number is stored as text and whether I'd like to change that or not. (of course I want that)

I can convert this to a number manually, but what should I add to my code to make this happen automatically?

Comment: Format the row/column as number first and then paste

Comment: I did that but that doesn't work... The entire column is formatted as "number".

Comment: Hmm That is strange. Is it possible to see a sample workbook?

Comment: I managed to achieve this by adding the following code: `Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("E1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("B8").Select`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of the values stored as text by using the "Text to Columns" feature.
I added the following code to my macro.

```
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("E1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Note that I first tried to format the entire column as "Number" but that didn't solve the problem.